# Dynamically load subdomains folder as root with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I'm trying to achieve, using `.htaccess`, so I can access all my projects with the configurations of one virtual host setup, and one URL defined in the hosts file. This will allow me to drop a project in the folder and it will function without having me to do any other configurations, and save a lot of time while working.

Example A: `prestige.projects.dev` is hosted on `D:/projects/prestige` etc.

Example B: `newproject.projects.dev` is hosted on `D:/projects/newproject` etc.

The code below works for the specific situation of Example A, but I can't figure out how to make it work 'dynamically' for all projects. My goal is to make `prestige` a wildcard. For example: `newproject.projects.dev` should *automatically* load the contents of `D:/projects/newproject`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^prestige\.projects\.dev$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/prestige/
RewriteRule (.*) /prestige/$1
```

I'm open to other suggestions than this method, as long as the goal is achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]+)\.projects\.dev [NC]
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI} /%1" !^(/[^/]+)[^\s]*\s\1$
RewriteRule (.*) /%1/$1 [L]
```

`%1` is a backreference to the captured group in the last matched *CondPattern*.

The second `RewriteCond` directive is the "wildcard" version of your hardcoded check to make sure the `REQUEST_URI` does not already start with the directory that matches the subdomain - thus preventing a rewrite loop.

The string `%{REQUEST_URI} /%1` (which expands to a string of the form "`/<directory>/<anything> /<subdomain>`" after the first rewrite) is matched against the regex `^(/[^/]+)[^\s]*\s\1$`, which checks to see if `/<directory>` is the same as `/<subdomain` (`\1` being an internal backreference to the captured group in the regex). Only if this does not match then the `RewriteRule` *substitution* occurs - in the same way your current rule works.

Comment: Maybe add a check, if `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1` is a directory.

Comment: I've updated my answer. This now more closely mimics your check against `REQUEST_URI`, thus preventing direct requests for the subdomain/directory being rewritten (this negates the need for the `REDIRECT_STATUS` check). This does still allow the directory to be accessed directly - although that shouldn't be a problem if this environment is solely used for development (an _external redirect_ can be implemented if required).

Comment: I've not implemented the directory check that Olaf suggested since I think it would be preferable to fail with a 404, rather than silently. Unless the default response when accessing the document root (of the subdomain) is a 404 response?

Comment: This solution is exactly what i was looking for, the checking for directory is indeed not necessarily as the 404 is the expected result. I thank-you!